# ignoring cosmosdb info logs while developping Azure functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developping Azure functions locally on vscode and I query a distant cosmosdb using the azure.cosmos module.

My problem is that each query to the cosmosdb produces logs of info (or verbose) logs in my terminal and makes reading my own `logging.info()` outputs quite hard to read.

logs I want to hide:

```
[2022-08-31T08:50:00.643Z] Request URL: 'https://xxx-norwayeast.documents.azure.com:443/dbs'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-documentdb-query-iscontinuationexpected': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-consistency-level': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'authorization': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    'Content-Length': '12'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-cosmos/4.2.0 Python/3.9.12 (Windows-10-10.0.25188-SP0)'
A body is sent with the request
```

I do not know how to set the log level to ignore the cosmosdb logs (ideally only getting the warning/error logs) or to only print my own logs when I need to.

my host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "%TaskHub%"
    }
  }
}
```

my function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": "orchestrationTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be a setting on the Azure Function, you can do that using the [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.YourFunctionName.User": "Information",
      "Function": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```